# Display Student ID and highest score from an array

Tags: c++

I am having issues figuring out how to properly display a student's ID, out of 10 students, along with the highest score. For examle, if student 4 had the highest score if would display said student's ID and their score. I would like to add the student's first and last name as well, if possible. My code is as follows:

```
// HW2.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.

     #include <iostream>
     using namespace std;

     double TestScore(double score);

     struct studentType {
        string studentFName;
        string studentLName;
        double testScore;
        int studentID;
        double highScore;
     };

     int main()
     {
        // # of students
    studentType student[10];

    // For loop to get user input for the 10 students
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        cout << "Student ID: ";
        cin >> student[i].studentID;
        cout << "Student First Name: ";
        cin >> student[i].studentFName;
        cout << "Student Last Name: ";
        cin >> student[i].studentLName;
        cout << "Student's Test Score: ";
        cin >> student[i].testScore;
        cout << endl;
        //Calls TestScore function

        student[i].testScore = TestScore(student[i].testScore);
    }
        //Displays student ID and score v code that I need help on
        //cout <<student[i].studentID << " has the highest score, which is "<< TestScore;
 }

    double TestScore(double score)
 {

    double newScore = 0;

    //Determines student with highest score
    for (int n = 0; n < 10; n++) {
        if (score > newScore)
        {
            newScore = score;
        }
    }
    return newScore;
 }
```

It needs to : 
1) read the students’ data into the array.
2) find the highest test score.
3) print the names of the students having the highest test score.

Comment: What happens when you run your code? What do you want it to do differently?

Comment: What do you want the program to do if two or more students share the high score?

Comment: It runs but I need it to properly display the student from the array that has the highest score. if gives me an error that the i in student[i] is undefined. This I know is an error because I was doing it outside the for loop. But if I leave it in the for loop it would repeat the process 10 times. And I would want it to display all the students with the highest score

Comment: Hint: [std::max_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element)

Comment: @ChrisMM if I had two people with the same score how would I display both? Make another for loop?

Comment: You can return a list of indices which all have the same top score. You'd then loop over that list to print out the relevant data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `TestScore` function doesn't really do anything. I've modified your code to have a function which returns the index of the student with the best score. Using this index, you can then access that element of the array, and print out its details.

````
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct studentType {
    string studentFName;
    string studentLName;
    double testScore;
    int studentID;
    double highScore;
};

int getBestStudent( studentType student[10] );

int main() {
   // # of students
    studentType student[10];

    // For loop to get user input for the 10 students
    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {

        cout << "Student ID: ";
        cin >> student[i].studentID;
        cout << "Student First Name: ";
        cin >> student[i].studentFName;
        cout << "Student Last Name: ";
        cin >> student[i].studentLName;
        cout << "Student's Test Score: ";
        cin >> student[i].testScore;
        cout << endl;
    }
    // Displays student ID and score v code that I need help on
    int best = getBestStudent( student );
    cout <<student[best].studentFName << " " << student[best].studentLName << " has the highest score, which is "<< student[best].testScore;
}

int getBestStudent( studentType student[10] ) {

    int best = 0;

    //Determines student with highest score
    for ( int n = 1; n < 10; n++ ) {
        if ( student[n].testScore > student[best].testScore ) {
            best = n;
        }
    }
    return best;
}```
````